# How to get text in popup control extender?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i am using a popup control extender.but i am getting only index of selected value from radiobutton list.I want to get the text

Below is my source code

```
<div class="FloatRight">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTeam" runat="server" Width="150px" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                            <br />
                            <asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server">
                                <div style="border: 1px outset white; width: 100px">
                                    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1">
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbteam" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbteam_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                </div>
                            </asp:Panel>
                            <cc1:PopupControlExtender ID="txtTeam_PopupControlExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
```

and this is server side

```
protected void rbteam_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rbteam.SelectedValue))
        {

            txtTeam_PopupControlExtender.Commit(rbteam.SelectedValue);

        }
       else 
        {

            txtTeam_PopupControlExtender.Cancel();
        }

       rbteam.ClearSelection();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txtTeam_PopupControlExtender.Commit(rbteam.SelectedItem.Text);
```